# Python Pandas group by nth row provided a specific column has same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Use case: I have 1 min candle (interval) stock data (date, time, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price) for a week and want to convert them into 5 mins, 10 mins, 15 mins, 1-hour interval. I am able to split them based on the row count (5 one-minute candle per every 5-min candle) but facing difficulty to cut off a day end. i.e. if there are only 4 one-minute candles left, system should process only them to define last candle but at present it's taking next day first 1-min candle. Help me on how to add grouping by date

Example 1: Input vs Expected Output

```
date   time  open  high  low  close
0  date1  time1    10    18    8     18
1  date1  time2    12    22   10     16
2  date1  time3    14    16   12     15
3  date1  time4    11    15    9     14
4  date2  time5    24    26   22     25
5  date2  time6    31    45    9     24

    date   time  open  high  low  close
0  date1  time2    10    22    8     16
1  date1  time4    14    16    9     14
2  date2  time6    24    45    9     24
```

Example 2: Input vs Expected Output

```
date   time  open  high  low  close
0  date1  time1    10    18    8     18
1  date1  time2    12    22   10     16
2  date1  time3    14    16   12     15
3  date2  time4    11    15    9     14
4  date2  time5    24    26   22     25
5  date2  time6    31    45    9     24

    date   time  open  high  low  close
0  date1  time2    10    22    8     16
1  date1  time3    14    16   12     15
2  date2  time5    24    26   22     25
3  date2  time6    31    45    9     24
```

Current working code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
    
 data = [['date1', 'time1', 10, 18 , 8, 18 ], ['date1', 'time1', 12, 22 , 10, 16 ],['date1', 'time1', 14, 16 , 12, 15 ],['date1', 'time4', 11, 15 , 9, 14 ],['date2', 'time5', 24, 26 , 22, 25 ],['date2', 'time6', 31, 45 , 9, 24 ]]
 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'time', 'open', 'high','low', 'close'])
 print (df)

# Todo: to cut off the grouping at day end start fresh for new day data

df1 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 2).agg({"date":"last", "time":"last","open":"first","high":"max","low":"min","close":"last"})


print(df1)
```

Comment: Use the `datetime` type, something like `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+df['time'])`, and then resample with `asfreq('5Min')`.

Comment: You can also do `df.groupby(['date', np.arange(len(df.index)) // 2])...` but `datetime` type makes more sense to me.

Comment: Will try asfreq() and groupby[] is a quick fix

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked:

By the way, I am from India and the market operates from 9:15 AM to 3:30 PM. So, the base for 10 mins candle is 5 here.

```
  df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]+" "+df["time"])
 

  df_5mins= df.set_index('timestamp').resample('5min', base=0).mean().dropna()
  # base is required for 10 mins     
  df_10mins= df.set_index('timestamp').resample('10min', base=5).mean().dropna()
  # base is not required for 15 mins as the default value is 0. same for 5 mins
  df_15min = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('15min').mean().dropna()
```